# how to extract a zip folder and store it in internal storage , android/data/ using kotlin on a button click

Tags: android, kotlin

I am making an android app in Kotlin, in which I want a button when a user clicks a button then the zip file should extract in that android/data/

I have a zip file which i have created which contains folder and inside that folder there is sub-folder, so i want to store that main folder or we can say extracted zip inside internal storage -> android/data/ "here"

So please can anyone help in detail as I am new to kotlin, how can i do it using kotlin in android studio.

Comment: I'm not sure how this question relates to Android Studio.

Comment: sir this is related to android studio only, i am making a android app, in which i want a button when a user click a button then the zip file should extract in that android/data/

Comment: No, it's not related to Android Studio in the least. That's a question on general Android development, **not** the Android Studio IDE itself (which is what the tag is for). The fact that you happen to be using Android Studio for the development is irrelevant - it's still not *about* the IDE itself. Please consult the tag usage guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip4j` library to extract your zip file
what you will have to do is provide the path of zip and destination rest will be the work of `zip4j` library.

Take a look here [zip4j library](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j)

You can also create zip files programmatically using this library.

Comment: but you haven't answer the second part of this question which is main thing that is how to store it inside android/data folder of internal storage

Comment: You can store files in your app data folder which by giving the path of folder 
like this 

context?.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

you can specify your own directory too

Comment: please read question again , i am asking to store file inside android/data
not android/data/appfolder

Comment: You should about the storage permission first. I think you can't access this directory you can only access public directories if you have read write permission.
But to store in your appfolder you don't need any permission. 
after android 10 you can't access private directories you will need managa all storage permission for this but also read about the polices to get manage all permission.